# C#/.NET I'm trying to create a login authentication for users, but my BCrypt verification is not working

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating a login and user verification system using C#/.NET. This is my first time creating such a system so I need some guidance or strategies on how to go about accomplishing this. Thank you

## Login Request

```
public class UserLoginRequest
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

## Login Result

```
public class LoginResult
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

## Login SERVICE

```
public LoginResult Login(UserLoginRequest login)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "User_GetByEmail";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", login.Email);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            { 
                reader.Read();
                LoginResult result = new LoginResult();
                string PasswordHash = "";
                {
                    result.Id = (int)reader["Id"];
                    result.Email = (string)reader["Email"];
                    PasswordHash = (string)reader["PasswordHash"];
                };

                if (BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(login.Password, PasswordHash))
                {
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

## Login Controller

```
    [HttpPost, Route("api/login")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Login(UserLoginRequest userLogin)
    {
        LoginResult result = userService.Login(userLogin);
        if (result != null && result.Id.HasValue)
        { 
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new ErrorResponse("Invalid username or password"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you hash UserLoginRequest.PasswordHash? Is your user input hashed?

Comment: The first parameter of `Verify` must be the raw password, not the hash. `BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify("abcd", BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword("abcd"))`

Comment: Your `if(BCrypt...){return result;}{return result;} returns teh same stuff. Is this on purpose?

Comment: @kapsi no it is not hashed

Comment: @Kalten I changed it to a raw password now

Comment: @LosManos No that was just for testing purposes, it now return null

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the problem was in my stored procedure where i did not allow enough characters to be passed into the database